How to calculate the intersection of two UIBezierpaths
I need to calculate the intersection of two irregular UIBezierpaths say to closed paths representing irregular shapes. Problem is I don't even know how to get started on this. I've searched for libraries that could help but the only thing I found is a git repository missing files so it won't compile.

It's a bit more complicated of a question than you might think, and the solution depends on exactly what you're trying to do. What do you really mean (or think you mean) by "intersection"?

@DonMag Ok so the user draws an irregular selection path around part of a UIView that contains subviews. The irregular path will intersect one or more of the subviews. So I convert the subviews (UIImageViews) rectangle to a UIBezierPath and try to figure out what the intersection between that paths is because i need to remove the pixels of the subviews image inside of the part of the UIBezierPath that intersects the subview. I hope I explained that clearly enough.

We can use Instance Methods on CGPath -- either retrieved from UIBezierPath or, a bit easier, working directly with CGMutablePath.
See the Apple docs under Instance Methods here.
Depending on what you really want to do, though, you might not need to manipulate your path at all. You can use it as a mask ... you can use path contains(_ point: CGPoint) ... and so on.
But -- here is a really quick example of using CGPath intersection(_:using:)
I'll make a few assumptions, such as you are adding an image view to a view subclass; tracking the touch began, moved, ended; using a CAShapeLayer to "draw" the path outline; etc.
Looks kinda like this (tapping anywhere outside the gray frame will "clip" the path and fill it with green):


Simple UIView subclass

has a centered image view, with some padding on the sides (so we can "draw" outside the image)
draws a 2-point width path outline
closes the path on touches ended
has a public func to "clip" the drawn path with the image view's frame


class MyCanvasView: UIView {
    
    let imgView = UIImageView()
    
    private var myPath: CGMutablePath!
    private var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    private func commonInit() {
        imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(imgView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            imgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 60.0),
            imgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 60.0),
            imgView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -60.0),
            imgView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -60.0),
        ])
        
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.systemRed.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2
        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        
        // in case there is no image set
        imgView.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let t = touches.first else { return }
        let pt = t.location(in: self)
        myPath = CGMutablePath()
        myPath.move(to: pt)
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.path = myPath
    }
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let t = touches.first else { return }
        let pt = t.location(in: self)
        myPath.addLine(to: pt)
        shapeLayer.path = myPath
    }
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let t = touches.first else { return }
        let pt = t.location(in: self)
        myPath.closeSubpath()
        shapeLayer.path = myPath
    }

    public func clipPath() {
        let imgPath = CGMutablePath(rect: imgView.frame, transform: nil)
        let clippedPath = imgPath.intersection(myPath)
        shapeLayer.path = clippedPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
    }
}


Test View Controller class
class TestPathsVC: UIViewController {
    
    let canvasView = MyCanvasView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        canvasView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(canvasView)
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            canvasView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            canvasView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            canvasView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            canvasView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: canvasView.widthAnchor),
        ])
        
        if let img = UIImage(named: "testPic") {
            canvasView.imgView.image = img
        }
        
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        canvasView.clipPath()
    }
}


Wow ok thank you I'll work to adapt this to my code. My test case example was more straightforward than my actual app, so it'll take some tinkering on my part I'm sure but thank you

turns out CGPath has an intersection instance method as of iOS16 that does this. It then just becomes a matter of converting the path from the main window coordinates to the view with the image's coordinates But thank you for your answer it did help
